# When to use Request.RegisterForDispose?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

For ASP.NET Web API, I've been working on my own implementation of `IHttpControllerActivator` and am left wondering when (or why?) to use the `HttpRequestMessage` extension method "`RegisterForDispose`".

I see examples like this, and I can see the relevance in it, since IHttpController doesn't inherit IDisposable, and an implementation of IHttpController doesn't guarantee its own dispose logic.

```
public IHttpController Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)
{
    var controller = (IHttpController) _kernel.Get(controllerType);
    request.RegisterForDispose( new Release(()=> _kernel.Release(controller)));
    return controller;
}
```

But then I see something like this and begin to wonder:

```
public IHttpController Create(
    HttpRequestMessage request,
    HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor,
    Type controllerType)
{
    if (controllerType == typeof(RootController))
    {
        var disposableQuery = new DisposableStatusQuery();
        request.RegisterForDispose(disposableQuery);
        return new RootController(disposableQuery);
    }
    return null;
}
```

In this instance RootController isn't registered for disposal here, presumably because its an ApiController or MVC Controller? - And thus will dispose itself.

The instance of DisposableStatusQuery is registered for disposal since it's a disposable object, but why couldn't the controller dispose of the instance itself? RootController has knowledge of disposableQuery (or rather, it's interface or abstract base), so would know it's disposable.

When would I actually *need* to use HttpRequestMessage.RegisterForDispose?

Answer (score 1):

One scenario I've found it useful for: for a custom ActionFilter.

Because the Attribute is cached/re-used, items within the Attribute shouldn't rely on the controller to be disposed of (to my understanding - and probably with caveats)... so in order to create a custom attribute which isn't tied to a particular controller type/implementation, you can use this technique to clean up your stuff.  In my case, it's for an ambient DbContextScope attribute.

Answer (score 1):

`RegisterForDispose` it's a hook that will be called when the request is disposed. This is often used along with "some" of the dependency injection containers.

For instance, some containers (like Castle.Windsor) by default will **track** all dependencies that they resolve. This is according to Windsor ReleasePolicy `LifecycledComponentsReleasePolicy` which states that it will keep track of all components that were created. In other words your garbage collector will not be able to cleanup if your container still tracks your component. Which will result into memory leaks.

So for example when you define your own `IHttpControllerActivator` to use it with a dependency injection container it is in order to resolve the concrete controller and all its dependencies. At the end of the request you need to release all the created dependencies by the container otherwise you will end with a big memory leak. You have this opportunity doing it with `RegisterForDispose`

Answer (score 0):

I use RegisterForDispose with the DI container's. Based on [Blog post](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/10/03/DependencyInjectionInASPNETWebAPIWithCastleWindsor.aspx) I have implemented to dispose the container(Nested Container) after each request so that it clears all the objects which i has created.

Comment: Ploeh's blog post is a simple enough example where the controller won't necessarily dispose of itself, hence registering it for disposal. But what I'm interested in is scenarios like my second example (and I've seen code out there doing it this way). In this scenario the instance of DisposableStatusQuery is registered for disposal, but I see no reason why RootController couldn't dispose of it itself as part of its own disposal code. I understand the pattern being used here, but it feels like some examples I see are using it when unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

One may want to hook code around the life cycle of a request that (1) has little to do with controllers and (2) does not subclass the request type.

I would imagine the idiomatic form of such code takes the shape of extension methods on `HttpRequestMessage`, for example.  If the code allocates disposable resources, it would need to hook the disposal code to *something*.  I'm not too familiar with the various extension points of the ASP.NET pipeline, but I suppose hooking code just to dispose of resources at the end of the request processing stage was common enough to justify a dedicated registration mechanism for disposable resources (as opposed to more generally subscribing code to be executed).

Since you're asking, I found a nice example scenario in [this sample](https://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/643f51f6de9ccb009c0a0692c8836c094a55f30c#Samples/WebApi/OData/v3/ODataEFBatchSample/ODataEFBatchSample/Extensions/HttpRequestMessageExtensions.cs).  Here, an Entity Framework context is set as a property of the request, and must be disposed of properly.  While this property is intended to be used by controllers, they're not specific to any controller or controller super-class, so in my opinion this is a very sensible design choice.  If you're curious why, this is because these requests are "OData batch requests" and controller actions will be invoked multiple times over the lifetime of each request (once per "operation").  Certain operations are grouped into atomic "changesets" that must be wrapped in transactions at a higher-level than controllers (a dedicated mechanism is used: an `ODataBatchHandler`, so that the controllers themselves are oblivious to this).  Hence, controllers alone are not enough, as one cannot have them dispose of the context themselves in this scenario.

Hope this helps.